# "Different between for A and for B"

Tags: prepositions, idioms

As a variation of the comparison construction "Different **between** A and B", can I say "Different **between for** A and for B", or use other prepositions preceding the items being compared?

For example:

> - The heat-retention time with this mug differs **between with** coffee and **with** tea.
> - Data loading time with the computer differs **between for** USBDisk and **for** RAMDisk.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your intent correctly, I think you mean:

> **difference** between A and B

So you could say:

> The heat-retention time with this mug differs **between coffee and tea**.

According to the definition of [***between***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/between) sense 8, as a preposition:

> 8) from one or the other of   ⇒ "choose between love and duty"

Anyway you cannot have a preposition follow another preposition, so you cannot put *for* or *with* after *between*, as in your examples.